# spatie / laravel-translatable shows the default locale when I try to retrieve the translation that does not exist yet

Tags: laravel, localization, laravel-translatable

The problem is that I want a title with 3 languages (English, Italian, German). The user can add 3 titles on a form for each language which only the Italian is `required`. After that the titles are saved in db like this using `spatie / laravel-translatable`:

```
{"it":"Titolo in italiano.","en":"English title."}
```

The idea is that user can edit this titles but there is a problem.
On the form when trying to retrieve titles for English, Italian, German, when one of the titles for this languages is missing and I try to show it using:

`{{ $item->getTranslation('title_lang', 'de') }}`

It retrieves the default title as per default locale which is `'it'` in this case. So in case that Germa title is missing it shows the Italian one.

I wanted to show the input which would contain German title, otherwise to be empty in case of no title in German.

I don't know how can I can check on `blade` using `@if` statement or some other logic.
I tried desperately this but without success(no sense but I give it a try):

```
@if(isset($product->getTranslation('description_locale', 'de')))
    {{ $product->getTranslation('description_locale', 'de') }}
@endif
```

I looked at the docs but did not found something which can help me.

Has anyone any idea how to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: can you try to `$useFallbackLocale=false` param for not getting default locale string. https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable/blob/master/src/HasTranslations.php#L49

As: `$product->getTranslation('description_locale', 'de', false)`

Comment: Bro you're right! Thank you so much! I was blocked and nothing come to my mind. You can write this as an answer and I can accept it!

Comment: fyi: `@if(isset({{ $product->getTranslation('description_locale', 'de') }}))` should not contain `{{` and `}}` since you already are using Blade

Comment: @brombeer yeah that is so stupid, I was just confusing and did that, I know that `@if` should not conatin `{{}}` but I was just confused. Thanks anyway. I tried this without `{{}}` also and did not worked. Im editing the question but I already got the answer.

Comment: That might be because of the `isset()`, `@if($product->getTranslation('description_locale', 'de'))` should work, not tested though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try to `$useFallbackLocale=false` param for not getting default locale string.

You can check method usage from [source code](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable/blob/master/src/HasTranslations.php#L49).

As: `$product->getTranslation('description_locale', 'de', false)`